# Can Swift protocols be singleton?

Tags: swift, singleton, swift-protocols

I have tried using the single line singleton initialization(as in a class) for a singleton, here are some error screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Can you help me understand these errors, and also, if a singleton protocol is even possible or not?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot instantiate an instance of a protocol, only protocol adopters

Comment: I don't understand what it would mean to do that.  A singleton is an instance but you don't create instances of protocols.  Rather, you create instances of classes that may implement a protocol.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A protocol itself can't be a singleton. That wouldn't make any sense. A protocol is something that other types conform to.

But if you wanted to declare that things that conform to `Singleton` follow some rule, such as offering a `sharedInstance`, then that's fine. Your syntax is just incorrect. You need to use a `var` with `get` rather than `let`.

```
protocol Singleton {
    static var sharedInstance: Self { get }
}
```

In principle, you could automatically create this instance by providing a default implementation, but Swift doesn't allow you to create storage in an extension. While it would be possible to pull this off with some kind of global cache, it's hard to imagine it being worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain: `But if you wanted to declare that things that conform to Singleton follow some rule, such as offering a sharedInstance`

Comment: Anything that claims to conform to Singleton would need to provide a sharedInstance property. That's what protocols are for. You'd still need to implement that property for each type. (Note that if you're trying to automate singleton construction, you're almost certainly overusing singletons.)